# Clearcase find command in combination with Tcl Script and Batch-File: Redirection doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, find, redirect, tcl, clearcase

it's me again ;-)

I try to start the cleartool find command from a batch file. That batch files gets his arguments from a Tcl script.

Batch File:

```
 SET VERARG="version(\main\LATEST) && !lbtype(%3)"
 cleartool find . -version %VERARG% -print > Y:\x\Logs\%3.log
```

Tcl Script:

```
 set v_cmd "y:\\x\\clearcase_find_change.cmd $v_drive $v_path $v_label \n"
 set v_outp [exec cmd << $v_cmd]
```

When I start the batch file from command line, it works and it wrotes the hits to the log-file, but when I start it from Tcl, I see the hits in the command window, but it only creates the log-files with no content. I tested it already with a very simple batch file, which only contents a echo command and a redirection. That worked, I've also tried to use different drives, but with no success. I checked also the received arguments of the batch-file, but everything looked fine to me.

Simple Call, which worked:

```
Batch: echo %1 > Y:\x\%2.log
Tcl: set v_cmd "y:\\x\\simple_echo.cmd $v_lib $v_label \n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is missing a cmd directive to specify that the DOS session should execute *and then quit*:

```
set v_outp [exec cmd << $v_cmd /c]
```

or:

```
set v_outp [exec cmd /c << $v_cmd]
```

or:

```
set v_cmd "/c y:\\x\\clearcase_find_change.cmd $v_drive $v_path $v_label \n"
set v_outp [exec cmd << $v_cmd]
```

(to make sure the `/c` is passed first)

See [Tcl/Tk FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/tcl-faq/tk/windows/):

```
exec cmd.exe >&@stdout <@stdin /c dir
```

> will do the directory command for the current directory.
>   Check out the Windows help for the switches available under `cmd.exe`.
>   "`/c`" tells it to execute the command and then exit. "`/k`" tells it to execute the command and keep the DOS command interpreter active.
>   (Note that cmd.exe is the name of the MS-DOS interpreter on Windows NT.)

Comment: Possibility 1 and 2 won't even open the command window, possibility 3 generates an Tcl Error

Comment: @Kai: Ok. Basically, you need to play around with that `/c` option (first in a simple, non-ClearCase related, Tcl script for a simple command), and see if that works. Then adapt it to the ClearCase (cleartool) cmd command.